How to create a react app with typescript template on windows machine
I want to create a react application with typescript template.
npm version: 10.2.4
node version: 20.1.1
I tried the following commands but got errors:

First command npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript

Got error:
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path D:\usr
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\usr'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent


Second command npm create-react-app my-app --template typescript

Got error:
Unknown command: "create-react-app"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help```


Don't use CRA, it's no longer maintained: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2023/Dec/17/js-tdd-vite.html

I highly recommend Vite as suitable replacement... npm create vite@latest my-app -- --template react-ts

The error being reported is about your D:\usr directory. Is that your current working directory or have you configured npm to use that as a folder? Does that drive and directory exist?

a lot of the time this is because node/npm does not have permissions to access the folder.

You could just use npx create-next-app@latest, where you will get the option to use typescript.
From React docs: https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project

Worked for me as, First run
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
After that:
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
